# How to declare one-to-many using Fluent API without changing the model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many, ef-fluent-api

I have two classes as follows.

```
class Donkey
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

class Monkey
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Donkey Donkey { get; set; }  
}
```

Now I want to configure the schema so that the relation is set in the database. Using Fluent API, I'll go something like this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder model)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(model);
  model.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
  ...
  model.Entity<Monkey>
    .HasRequired(_ => _.Donkey)
    .WithMany(_ => _.Monkeys)
    .Map(_ => _.MapKey("DonkeyId"));
}
```

The problem is that now I **have to** declare a list of monkeys in the donkey. And I don't want to do that. I still want the monkey to point to a donkey using foreign key, so only required status won't do, because I need to specify my custom column name to store the FK pointing to the PK in the table of donkeys.

```
model.Entity<Monkey>.HasRequired(_ => _.Donkey);
```

So, the above lacks the mapping (and it doesn't compile when I just add it). Is there a way to work around it without actually changing the definition of *Donkey* class?

Comment: Just call another overload without parameters - `WithMany()`

Comment: @2kay That simple? Is it a recommended way? Will there be any dragons? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: According to docs, yes. Used it in prod, never seen any dragons )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Monkey>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Donkey)
            .WithMany();
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize there was such overload. Now, to map to a custom named column, can I simply use *MapKey* as I've shown in my question or are there any other issues to consider sprung from invokation of a different method?

Comment: You can add another overload like `.Map(x => x.MapKey("DonkeyId"));` or if you add another column to `Monkey` class, you can use `.HasForeignKey(x => x.DonkeyId);`

Comment: By the way, this was a great answer, so you're more than welcome to give it an equally great whack at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521800/how-to-declare-a-one-to-many-in-fluent-api-so-that-its-not-required). It's probably even easier.